# Migration of moment to date-fns toDate()

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, date-fns

I am migrating the momentjs to date-fns.
I am having some issues for the migration which moment uses local

I have for the actual status with moment something like this and I want to switch it to date-fns

```
locale = 'de-de';
  constructor() {
    moment.locale(this.locale);
  }
```